# Rotating Screen with Ctrl + Alt + Arrow Hotkey Stopped Working

Tags: graphics, rotation, screen, autohotkey, intel

I've always used the Ctrl + Alt + Arrow Hotkey to rotate my screen but it suddenly stopped working (maybe because of some inter update).

Whenever I try using the hotkey and Intel Graphics Command Center is open I instead get a notification saying: Hotkey: Rotate90 failed.

I had already downloaded the Intel Graphics Command Center and enabled this option from the System tab, and yes, I also enabled the Restart Apps option from windows' Setting>Account>Sing-in options.

One thing I find strange however is that whenever I close Intel Graphics Command Center I don't find the icon in the bottom-right corner of the taskbar, furthermore despite being active in the "Startup Apps" Setting's tab it doesn't automatically launch when I turn on the pc.

Please somebody help me I desperately need the hotkey, I cannot open the system settings every time T_T

Comment: Try to run the program as administrator and add it to Startup using the Task Scheduler (Check the Run with highest privileges box).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for a solution here, but you can give this a try. Rotates your screen to a choice of all four sides.

```
/*
; ╞═══════════ Pre-Notes ═══════════╡ 
» Ctrl + Alt + upArrow ↑↑↑↑ Flip Orientation ↑ Upside Down.
» Ctrl + Alt + leftArrow    →→→ Rotate Orientation → Right 90°.
» Ctrl + Alt + rightArrow ←←←   Rotate Orientation ← Left 90°.
» Ctrl + Alt + downArrow   ↓↓   Standard Orientation ↓.
; ╞──────── Pre-Notes End ────────╡ 
*/

; ╞═══════════ Auto-Execute ═══════════╡ 
#NoEnv ; Recommended for performance and future compatibility.
#Persistent ; Keeps a script permanently running until user closes it or ExitApp is encountered.
#SingleInstance, Force ; Determines whether a script is allowed to run again when it is already running.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
; ╞──────── Auto-Execute End ────────╡ 

lookup:={"^!down":[0,0],"^!left":[1,1],"^!up":[2,0],"^!right":[3,1]} 

Return

^!down::
^!right::
^!up::
^!left::

display := GetMonitorName("Window")

if (lookup[a_thisHotkey][2]){            ; ←←← Rotating to portrait.
    sRes:=strSplit((cRes:=screenRes_Get(display)),["x","@"])
    if (sRes[2] < sRes[1]) {
        cRes:=sRes[2] "x" sRes[1] "@" sRes[3]
    }
} else {                     ; ←←← Rotating to landscape.
    sRes:=strSplit((cRes:=screenRes_Get(display)),["x","@"])
    if (sRes[2] > sRes[1]) {
        cRes:=sRes[2] "x" sRes[1] "@" sRes[3]
    }
 }
screenRes_Set(cRes,display,lookup[a_thisHotkey][1])
Return

screenRes_Set(WxHaF, Disp:=0, orient:=0) {  
    Local DM, N:=VarSetCapacity(DM,220,0), F:=StrSplit(WxHaF,["x","@"],A_Space)
    Return DllCall("ChangeDisplaySettingsExW",(Disp=0 ? "Ptr" : "WStr"),Disp,"Ptr",NumPut(F[3],NumPut(F[2],NumPut(F[1]
    ,NumPut(32,NumPut(0x5C0080,NumPut(220,NumPut(orient,DM,84,"UInt")-20,"UShort")+2,"UInt")+92,"UInt"),"UInt")
    ,"UInt")+4,"UInt")-188, "Ptr",0, "Int",0, "Int",0)  
}
screenRes_Get(Disp:=0) { 
    Local DM, N:=VarSetCapacity(DM,220,0) 
    Return DllCall("EnumDisplaySettingsW", (Disp=0 ? "Ptr" : "WStr"),Disp, "Int",-1, "Ptr",&DM)=0 ? ""
        : Format("{:}x{:}@{:}", NumGet(DM,172,"UInt"),NumGet(DM,176,"UInt"),NumGet(DM,184,"UInt")) 
}

GetMonitorName(method := "Window", coords := "", default_to := "Nearest") {
    static default := {"Null": MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL := 0x0, "Primary": MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY := 0x1, "Nearest": MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST := 0x2}
    If (method = "Window")
        hMonitor := DllCall("MonitorFromWindow", "UInt", WinExist("A"), "UInt", default[default_to], "Ptr")
    Else if (method = "Point") {
        if coords
            x := coords[1], y := coords[2]
        Else
            MouseGetPos, x, y
        hMonitor := DllCall("MonitorFromPoint", "Int64", (x&0xFFFFFFFF) | (y<<32), "Int", default[default_to], "Ptr")
    }
    Else if (method = "Rect") {
        if !coords
            Throw % "Rect method requires coordinates"
        VarSetCapacity(RECT, 16, 0)
        NumPut(coords[4], NumPut(coords[3], NumPut(coords[2], NumPut(coords[1], &RECT, "UInt"), "UInt"), "UInt"), "UInt")
        hMonitor := DllCall("MonitorFromRect", "Ptr", &RECT, "UInt", default[default_to], "Ptr")
    }
    Else
        Throw % "Invalid method"
    NumPut(VarSetCapacity(MONITORINFOEX, 40 + (32 << !!A_IsUnicode)), MONITORINFOEX, 0, "UInt")
    DllCall("GetMonitorInfoW", "Ptr", hMonitor, "Ptr", &MONITORINFOEX)
    return StrGet(&MONITORINFOEX + 40, 32)
}


; ╞═══════════ Reload/Exit Routine ═══════════╡ 
RETURN

^Home::
    Reload       ; Ctrl + [Home]

^Esc::
     Gui, Destroy 
     ExitApp     ; Ctrl + [Esc]

; ╞──────── Reload/Exit Routine End ────────╡
```